# Unable to boot Ubuntu after updating from Windows 8 to 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, grubrescue

I was having Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 (dual-boot) on my laptop. Recently I updated Windows 8 to 8.1. From then on when starting the system I cannot see the grub (directly boots into windows). I should get into setup to boot into Ubuntu which gives me this error

```
Error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

After reading few forums I have found few solutions that let me do this

```
set prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

this successfully lets me boot into Ubuntu.

But according to answer, later on typing these commands in terminal would let us get out of that problem from next time.

```
sudo update-grub (Run this in terminal after getting into Ubuntu)
sudo grub-install /dev/sda (Run this in terminal after getting into Ubuntu)
```

But its not in my case. I still face the same problem as previous. Please someone help me solving this issue.

Comment: What's the output of `fdisk -l`?